# Scratch online - Recursive - Factorial

Tags: recursion, mit-scratch

I can't figure out how to get my recursive call to work in Scratch. Can anyone make any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 4):

`change result by (result * number1)` increases `result` by `result * number1`. You want to set `result` directly to `result * number1`, so use a `set ... to ...` block instead.